# Firebase Dynamic Links API has not been used in project

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, google-developers-console

I have implemented Firebase Dynamic links REST api in C#. but when my code runs it give me error like this

```
Exception Message: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Firebase Dynamic Links API has not been used in project 480870517113 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/overview?project=480870517113 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console API activation",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/overview?project=480870517113"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have enable Firebase Dynamic Link api in [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=nimble-acrobat-91008), but i am clueless how can i fix this issue. do it needs more configurations ? Any help would be appreciated.